# How can I create an XML document starting from data retrieved from a database using WSO2 techonologies?

Tags: wso2, middleware, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am absolutly new in **WSO2** technology. I am working on a **WSO2 Enterprise Integrator** project using **ESB** and **Data Service Server** to extract some data from database tables.

So what I have to do is to generate a complex XML document starting from the data retrieved from the database by some queries.

So I have to:

- Perform some queries using **Data Service Server**
- Then using these retrieved data to build an XML document that use these data for the XML field values, something like this:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <singleField>value related to a record obtained by QUERY 1</singleField>

  <multipleField>value related to a record obtained by QUERY 1</multipleField>
  <multipleField>value related to a record obtained by QUERY 1</multipleField>
  <multipleField>value related to a record obtained by QUERY 1</multipleField>
  ```

So for example I will have 2 different simple select query:

- **QUERY 1:** that always will return a **single row**: the obtained value have to be putted as value of the **...** XML field
- **QUERY 2:** that may return multiple record, so for each of the returned record I have to put a new **...** element into my XML (using the related record value obtained by the query as value of this XML element).

WSO2 allows me to create an XML document in this way? What is the best tool (in WSO2 techonlogies set) to do it?

Comment: try with xslt mediator...you can create your xls transformation and invoke it with the xslt mediator.

Comment: I am not sure what your final aim is, but you can probably do it in DSS as well. If you use the Management console, you can create a service, using the wizard. Then you can create the two queries and the first query, in its result could call the second query - note that the params for the second query should either come with the first query (i.e. in the request) or from the result of the first query (the columns). Also, note that the multiple elements would have a parent element. If you want to remove the parent element, then you should use xslt.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a proxy service , that will invoke a soap data service and write it to a file for you

- Generate or create the data service via the DSS : (sql -> soap service (DSS))

> https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS310/Developing+Data+Services

- Integrate with the Data Service via an ESB Proxy service. (soap service (DSS) -> proxy (ESB) -> file) The output of the file can be done via :

  1. VFS transport (http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-example-file-processing/)
  2. File connector (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector+Version+2)

Comment: mmm...it seems to me that this tutorial is more related about how to expose a web service, where is the section related to the XML creation starting from the database content?

Comment: I see what you are saying. Ok , so the DSS can give you the XML structure (via a service) , and then the ESB can output it to the file for you. See edited question above.